# python lambda not return correct value

Tags: python, pandas

I am just start learning lambda, why I only getting 1 condition not 2 ? also is there a way to write this code shorter ?

```
df['numup'] = (pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))
df['nump'] = df['numup'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'true' else '0')
return : 
80    False
81     True
82    False
83    False
Name: numup, dtype: bool
80    0
81    0
82    0
83    0
Name: nump, dtype: object
```

if I use this code I get an error

```
df['numup'] = df.apply(lambda x: '1' if ((pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))) else '0')
```

Comment: Because the values are `True`, not `'true'`…!? So, `'1' if x else '0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first set of code failed because `x == 'true'` is doing a string checking if the value in your pandas Series is the string 'true', which in your case, it is a boolean. So it should be `lambda x: '1' if x else '0'`

Your second set of code failed because `(pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))` is producing a pandas Series rather than a single boolean value.

If you want to put that in one line, you can either combine what you have, i.e. replace `df['numup']` with `(pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))` or take another approach:

`((pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))).astype(int)`

see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html

Comment: can you give an example how to make boolean in lambda ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? In case you don't know what is a boolean, it means that it is an object that has True or False value. See: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp

Comment: maybe my question is unclear. on your canswer you said my second set of code failed because it return pandas series rather than boolean value, that's what I asking if you can give me an example ( if there any) to make that comparision inside lambda into boolean value so that I can make code shorter and clear, instead I have to type `df['numup'] = (pn> pc)& (pn.shift(-1) < pc.shift(-1))
df['nump'] = df['numup'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'true' else '0')` 2 lines code, I can make 1 line code.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a way you can do that in one line at a reasonable length, it does not involve lambda though. You can directly convert a boolean Series to an integer Series using `astype`